# Как запустить процесс не через System.Diagnostics.Process?

Tags: c#

Есть ли альтернативные способы, чтобы запущенный процесс не был дочерним для текущего?

Comment: Можно через WMI `Win32_Process.Create`.

Comment: @PetSerAl, Не ну так то можно запустить cmd а через нее запустить программу, но я не настолько извращенец :)

Comment: Процесс вроде бы и не запускается как дочерний. Как именно вы запускаете?

Answer (score 1):

```
var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c echo Foo && echo Bar";
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.Start();
```

Comment: Тема звучит как "... **НЕ** через System.Diagnostics.Process"